# Видео на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Товарищи добрый день!
Нужна помощь, как сделать чтобы кликая на иконку "проигрывать" включалось видео, а после завершения снова исчезала?

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-description__video {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 620px;
    max-height: 620px;
}

.main-description-video__inner{
    position: relative;
}

.main-description__content__video{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
}

.main-description__content__img{
      width: 620px;
      height: 620px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
    }
}

.main-description__video_control{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 35px
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    background-color: #5da8ef;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.main-description__video_control_img{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-35%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-35%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-35%, -50%);
        width: 35%;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        box-shadow: -2px -2px 35px
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
        background-color: #5da8ef;
        border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="main-description__video">
    <div class="main-description-video__inner">
    <video class="main-description__content__video"  src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/a9c84e19-1ffc-4c0b-b7c6-2a099b29bf0d" preload="none"></video>
  <img class="main-description__content__img" src=https://www.pechnik.su/upload/iblock/73a/6251e8fdcf3d1e162eb14ec93f00e149.JPG.jpg alt="Hearthstone">
  </div>
  <div class="main-description__video_control">
    <img class="main-description__video_control_img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/play-button-web-icon-multimedia-control-vector-id1064168804?k=6&m=1064168804&s=170667a&w=0&h=2sucm2NOVfGpuCYWF5C4dx53MizQaDKrzfB8XWQs0zA=" alt="Play">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему видео фреймом не вставиь и не использовать api ?

Comment: Это просто пример ссылки на видео. Ссылки на видео будут из разных источников (локально / на внешние ресурсы). Я не уверен что фреймом можно решить данную проблему

Comment: тогда https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events или вместе с методами https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp